# What happens to the references when a code is Compied in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I never understand , What actually happens to the the external DLLs when code is compiled by the compiler and converted to Intermediate code to run on CLR.

Does DLL code added to the Intermediate code and the references are not longer needed on the new machine or just the path of added DLLs are stored and we need those DLLs on our drive to run the program.

Comment: "Does DLL code ... are not longer needed" - just delete some/all of your dlls and see a result.

Comment: Have you tried referencing an external dll, then deleting it and trying to run your application? Wouldn't it be a simple test that would answer your question?

Comment: No, the DLL need to present in the same directory as your program.  This happens automatically, the only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: Okay. Let me Check.

Comment: Over-simplified explanation: The libraries are compiled to IL too. Then all the IL code is JIT compiled the first time you run it.

Comment: Please be careful not to delete anything important without making a back up first!

Comment: Get a copy of CLR Via C# and read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally (ie. there are some exceptions) the referenced assembly needs to be on the deployment system. All that is included in your assembly is the assembly name (this includes version and possibly signature).

Assembly binding (involving the GAC, config overrides etc.) is applied at runtime to get the right assembly. The rules depend on how the app domain was set up (eg. extra folders can be added, which is why ASP.NET web apps apply different rules).

There are various cases where the reference can be embedded (including referencing ActiveX when the right options are set and use of the assembly binding tool).

Comment: Yes.  I did that. When we reference an external Assembly (dll) to our project , it copied that assemble to the /bin/debug alongwith compiled Binary.
Thanks.